# xrandr doesn't list display port

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia, troubleshooting

**Edit 6**
After upgrading to ubuntu 21.10 the remaining issue with gl support is solved magically after the upgrade.

**Edit 5**

I started by comparing via `meld` `/etc/X11`, `/etc/modprobe.d` and `/lib/modprobe.d` and noticed that in my actual system there was a file `nvidia-kms.conf` with the following content:

```
# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
# Set value to 1 to enable modesetting
options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

Since this file was missing in the USB installation, I tried to set the value to 0 instead of 1 with success.

Now it seems to work. However as far as I know the modset value 1 is to avoid screen tearing. So I have to watch if any tearing problems appear (didn't notice any so far). I also don't understand why using the value 1 stops the external ports from working. So there may be another underlying issue and I don't consider the issue completely solved so far.

I have the feeling that it might have to do something with wayland (which I actually don't need since I use xmonad).

Furthermore the GL part in the output of `inxi` is still missing and `glxgears` not working. I noticed that there is a file `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so` in my USB system which doesn't exist in my actual system. I am not sure if it's save just to copy the file  <s>and didn't an ubuntu package delivering this file so far</s>. The file is contained in the [xserver-xorg-core](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/xserver-xorg-core_1.20.11-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html) package. Reinstalling it maked the file appear, but didn't resolve the inxi report or glxgears (after rebooting).

**Edit 4**
I just created a persistent live USB Stick and installed the nvidia drivers there using `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` (version 390). In the USB Stick system it works.

Now my idea is to find out the relevant diff between the configs to find the source of the error in my actual system. However I don't really know that files or directories I should compare. What would you suggest.

**Edit 3**

[Xorg.log pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UB8NX5ts)

I noticed that it `failed to load module "glamoregl" (module does not exist, 0)`, this may be explain the missing GL part in the Edit 2. But I didn't find any glamorgl module to install in ubuntu 21.04 nor don't see how this relates to my main problem that the external ports are not detected. That GL is missing some way seems to be confirmed by `glxgears` which doesn't start but gives me the following error message:

```
glxgears 
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  24
  Current serial number in output stream:  25
```

**Edit 2**

After installing and uninstalling the driver in several ways I didn't have any success, but I noticed that the inxi output is a bit different (no GL support):

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] vendor: Lenovo driver: nvidia v: 390.144 
           bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting,nvidia 
           unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: N/A v: N/A direct render: N/A
```

Also the `nvidia-smi` output looks a bit different:

```
Sat Jan  1 17:29:52 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.144                Driver Version: 390.144                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K2000M       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   41C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     70MiB /  1999MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      4088      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            67MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I am totally lost. Not that in my original question I used version 430 and now 390 (which was the recommended driver for my card), but the problem is essentially the same.

**Edit**: I have the same problem (described below) again with ubuntu 21.04 after installing nvidia again (I used noveau in the meantime) via `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.

Output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
nvidia-smi
Tue Dec 28 20:41:50 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.144                Driver Version: 390.144                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K2000M       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      5MiB /  1999MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you need the output of other log files or tools, let my know, I will add it.

**Original question**

My laptop (Thinkpad W530) has a VGA and a mini DP port (OR a DP port via docking station). Ubuntu 18.04, xrandr in particular doesn't seem to recognize the DP. For example if I run `xrandr` gives me

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So not only the external monitor on DP isn't recognized but even the port itself doesn't seem to be recognized (it doesn't show something like "DP... disconnected").

If I check `prime-select query` I get `nvidia`. I am using nvidia driver 430.

I should add that the external monitor works with a live usb stick and that it worked in the past. However I didn't use it for several month, so it might be that I screwed something up in the meantime. Thus I don't think that there is not a bug but a misconfiguration somewhere.

What can I do to identify the source of the problem and how can I fix it (but I don't want to reinstall the entire system)?

If I ask `nvidia-settings` to detect external screens it also finds nothing.

I also tried to change in BIOS settings from optimus to discrete graphics. But then I wasn't even able to login to my graphical interface (I am using `xmonad` as WM without display manager, just using `startx`).

[Here](https://pastebin.com/YGc8V3gD) is my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga`:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:21f5]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] [10de:0ffb] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] [17aa:21f5]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

output of `inxi -Gx`:

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: modesetting,nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Quadro K2000M/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.09 Direct Render: Yes
```

and `sudo lshw -class video | grep driver=` gives:

```
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

`lsmod | grep nvidia` gives

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm            815104  0
nvidia_drm             45056  4
nvidia_modeset       1101824  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              18448384  98 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 nvidia_drm,i915
ipmi_msghandler        53248  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
drm                   401408  7 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
```

I also checked `lsmod vesa` and `lsmod nouveau` to see if there was a fallback to vesa or nouveau. But this results in no output.

Comment: You are using the closed source `nvidia` driver, which, AFAIK, doesn't properly integrate with `xrandr`, and uses its own system to handle the video outputs (DP etc.). Trying `nouveau` is the right experiment, but `lsmod` won't force the `nvidia` driver out, so you might need to deinstall some packages and install some others, at least temporarily.

Comment: Actually I want to use the nvidia driver (as I said it already worked in the past). Maybe I will try the nouveau driver (better than nothing). Do do so, I should only `sudo apt-get purge '*nvidia*'` and reboot (the nouveau driver itself seems to be installed already). Is this correct?

Comment: Looking at the Xorg.log, the nvidia driver actually looks at all 7 outputs DFP-0 to DFP-6, but can't find anything that's connected. Maybe your laptop needs some extra driver to manage connections between the both graphics card outputs and your DP port?

Comment: What does "DFP-x" exactly mean?

Comment: See [Appendix C](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.137/README/displaydevicenames.html): *if the driver communicates using TMDS, LVDS, or DP, then the name is "DFP"*. Basically these are digital ports where different kinds of digital outputs will hook up to the GPU.

Comment: Can you specifiy which "extra driver" you mean?

Comment: I can't, because this is very hardware specific - laptops have a variety of different additional hardware to connect the graphics outputs to the chips. The attempt at the general framework is called [vga switcheroo](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/gpu/vga-switcheroo.html), but AFAIK, there are still quite a few laptops which need their own drivers, or may not have any drivers for this part (yet). So that will need some googling.

Comment: @dirkt: I tried the nouveau driver as a workaround and the external monitor works now. However this is only the second best option to me and I wish that the nvidia driver works as well. With the nouveau driver I have also a follow up question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/517139/5289

Comment: Hm. nouveau working and nvidia not working is strange indeed.

Comment: Hmmm nvidia-smi tells you are using driver 390.144 but you write "I am using nvidia driver 430." What does /usr/bin/nvidia-settings tell ?

Comment: OK then please repost the Xorg.log corresponding to your present configuration. The one you posted dates frome the times you were using nouveau.

Comment: @MC68020 See my edit above.

Comment: All right then, I understand better. WARNING! I am old school, stuck to a 340 version of nvidia drivers (that is no modesetting) with absolutely no knowledge of your particular distro. (I build my system myself from sources). This being said, what I read from your Xorg.log would tell me that A/ you are mixing the nvidia proprietary driver with nouveau. This, in my world would mean that the kernel configuration is faulty. (I can provide details) B/ Your system is using a nvidia blob that was built for a kernel version much older than the one you are running. => It must be rebuilt.

Comment: `lsmod | grep nouveau` results in nothing.

Comment: `nouveau` is also blacklisted.

Comment: About B): How do I check if the nvidia driver version should work (or not) with my kernel version?

Comment: nouveau is indeed loaded ([324.198] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau" [324.198] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so...) It should not. => Kernel config pb. For whatever reason I ignore it ends up being unloaded this explaining your lsmod|grep nouveau output.

Comment: Don't worry with the version. AFAIK, 390 is compatible up to 5.15. The problem with modules is not there. Drivers depends on symbols / code from the kernel. => they must be rebuild each time the kernel is rebuilt / adapted each time the kernel is changed. This is not a problem for in-kernel drivers that will be automatically rebuilt with the kernel, however, external modules have to be rebuilt "manually". I don't know how this is achieved under your distro. Anyway, this being a secondary problem. Start fixing your kernel conf first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132803/discussion-between-student-and-mc68020).