# Why does inxi report that I am using the nvidia (which is deinstalled) and not the nouveau driver?

Tags: graphics, nouveau, inxi

Since I had [problems with my external monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515555/5289) and the [nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us) drivers I tried to switch to the free [nouveau](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) driver by uninstalling all nvidia packages, reinstalling the nouveau driver and deleting all nouveau blacklist entries in my `modconf.d`. Now the external monitor works as expected (if plugged in directly to the laptop), but [`inxi`](https://smxi.org/docs/inxi.htm) tells me that I am not using the nouveau driver but `nvidia` and that `nouveau` is unloaded:

```
$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6 drivers: modesetting,nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 2560x1600@59.97hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile version: 4.2 Mesa 18.2.8 Direct Render: Yes
```

What did I do wrong?

**Edit**:

- Inxi Version is: 2.3.56-00 and now I updated to 3.0.33-00 which tells me the following.

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] vendor: Lenovo driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile v: 4.2 Mesa 18.2.8 direct render: Yes
```

which seems to give the correct output.

- [Here](https://pastebin.com/AnBUxFfV) is my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`
- Here is the output of `lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
acpi_call              16384  0
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport    28672  0
vsock                  36864  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vmw_vmci               69632  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
vboxdrv               471040  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  0
bnep                   20480  2
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  11 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
binfmt_misc            20480  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
arc4                   16384  2
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             212992  0
rtl8192ce              65536  0
kvm                   598016  1 kvm_intel
rtl_pci                32768  1 rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        57344  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_pci,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192ce
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
input_leds             16384  0
nouveau              1716224  1
serio_raw              16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              622592  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
lpc_ich                24576  0
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
thinkpad_acpi          94208  1
snd_pcm                98304  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
snd                    81920  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_pcm
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                   106496  1 nouveau
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mac_hid                16384  0
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  6
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
algif_skcipher         16384  0
af_alg                 24576  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               40960  1
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
i915                 1617920  3
pcbc                   16384  0
aesni_intel           188416  6
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 i915,nouveau
cryptd                 24576  4 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               147456  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
firewire_ohci          40960  0
pata_acpi              16384  0
e1000e                249856  0
drm                   401408  7 drm_kms_helper,i915,ttm,nouveau
sdhci_pci              32768  0
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
sdhci                  49152  1 sdhci_pci
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
wmi                    24576  3 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  45056  3 thinkpad_acpi,i915,nouveau
```

Comment: Check the /var/log/Xorg.*.log to see which X driver you are really using, and `lsmod` to see which modules are loaded (including the kernel drivers).

Comment: Make sure to run current inxi, there were a few weaknesses in terms of multiple drivers showing for Xorg in the 2.3 and older versions. Current is at 3.0.34. With that said, however, it's fairly likely that you are in fact running nvidia and modesetting, at least as far as Xorg loading the drivers and them not failing is concerned.

Comment: `dkms status` please. and `uname -r`